# Angular 4 AOT issues

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-aot

I have a huge Angular project that I would like to build using AOT compilation.

I followed this [guide](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) and could complete it and receive single file build.js.

How my site fails to load with error message in the console '

> **TypeError: t is undefined**

'. Is there any way to investigate and detect cause of the issue?

My index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=1">
  <title>Simulator</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/full/ckeditor.js"></script>
  <script src="http://cdn.ckeditor.com/4.7.0/full-all/plugins/divarea/plugin.js"></script>
  <script src="build.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks.

Comment: I've found `TypeError: t is undefined` is related to typescript version. Either an upgrade or downgrade in your package.json for typescript may fix the issue, but no promises.

Comment: I don't think we'll be able to fully diagnose just from the index.html, but a couple questions:
- are there no errors when you run the AOT build?
- when you run your project *without* AOT, do you get any errors?

Comment: Hi, Jack. My TypeScript version is the latest(2.4.2) So do you advice to downgrade it? When I run my build without AOT it runs without errors.